# How can I indicate which image should Chrome's Bookmark Manager use?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Chrome's Bookmark Manager will choose in a seemingly random manner which image it will use as the bookmarked page's thumbnail. In my case, it's choosing the worst of them all, the page's advertisement.

How can I sway it to use something else, like the person's picture?

[image: Chrome chooses my ad as a cover image!]

Comment: Can't reproduce. Is there a flag that must be enabled to get pictured bookmark ui?

Comment: @Mooseman it's automatic in their latest versions. http://thenextweb.com/google/2014/10/29/google-releases-new-stars-bookmark-manager-chrome/

Comment: Once the extension is downloaded. Got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No documentation, but I finally found it in the source of omgchrome.com:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="path/To/Image">
```